# SwiftUI List Keyboard Navigation Issue on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm experiencing a problem with keyboard navigation in a SwiftUI List on macOS. Navigation works for items visible on screen but doesn't extend to off-screen items; it stops at the last visible cell. This suggests keyboard scrolling isn't triggering new cell loading like mouse or touchpad scrolling does. Is this a known SwiftUI limitation, or is there a way to enable full keyboard navigation including loading additional items? Any advice or workaround would be helpful.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // Create an array of 500 integers
    private let numbers = Array(1...500)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail for \(number)")) {
                    Text("Item \(number)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Numbers")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```